# ZF2 PHP Warning: SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: soap, wsdl, entity, handle, zend-framework2

I am curently using ZF2-RC2 and trying to do a webservice in soap
I succeed to have my wsdl working by forcing the header, but for the server part, it is not working at all, and i get an error 500 telling me

> PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

The error is when i am doing the ->handle() part.

```
if(isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); 
    $autodiscover = new AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->setClass('WsClass')
                 ->setUri('http://adresse/ws/?wsdl');
    echo $autodiscover->toXml();
} else {

    // pointing to the current file here        
    $soap = new Server('http://adresse/ws/?wsdl');
    $soap->setClass('WsClass');
    $soap->handle();
}
exit;
```

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the URI in the AutoDiscover object to the wsdl. Try

```
$autodiscover->setClass('WsClass')
             ->setUri('http://adresse/ws');
```

Also, drop the / in the constructor of the server:

```
$soap = new Server('http://adresse/ws?wsdl');
```